# Getting garbage values while implementing linked list using structs in C# (unsafe construct)

Tags: c#, struct, unsafe

I was trying to verify a behavior reported by one of my friends, so I implemented Singly linked list in C# using struct. Since I had to use pointers so I used unsafe construct provided by C#. I also set the property to `Allow unsafe code` in build tab of project properties to make the code compilable.

Here is my complete code implementation:

```
public unsafe struct NodeList
{
    public Node* head;
    public Node* current;

    public  void AddNode(int d)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.data = d;
        n.link = null;
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = current = &n;
        }
        else
        {
            (*current).link = &n;
            current = &n;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(head->data);
    }

    public void TraverseNodes()
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp != null)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(temp -> data);
             temp= temp -> link;                
        }
    }
}

public unsafe struct Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node* link;
}

class Program
{
    private static void UnsafeDSImplementation()
    {
        var myLinkedList = new NodeList();
        myLinkedList.AddNode(2);
        myLinkedList.AddNode(4);
        myLinkedList.TraverseNodes();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnsafeDSImplementation();
    }
}
```

Errant observations:

1. Every time I go inside `AddNode` method and try to print node data value then for the first time I get 2 and second time I get 4. I'm wondering how come head is changing when I assign it only once while adding first node.
2. While traversing all the nodes - I get value of data for first node as 2243610 (this keeps changing on every run so it is garbage)  and `System.NullRefernceException` exception for second node iteration. Both nodes should print data correctly.

Now the behavior I'm getting may be due a mistake I've made in code or may be it is obvious as I'm using pointers from managed world. I need your help to figure this out.

Comment: why C tag if its c#?

Comment: And what has this question to do with C or C++? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: Updated tags. Removed C and C++. I thought it is about pointers and unsafe things so had added C and C++.

Comment: As for your problem, in `AddNode` isn't the variable `n` a *local* variable in the function, a local variable that will go out of scope once the function returns? What will happen with pointers to that local variable when that happens? Where will they point?

Comment: You are storing pointers to stack allocated variable, hence it should not be a surprise that you get garbage.

Comment: Now I got it @IvanStoev that the stack allocation to function level local variables was getting deallocated. In fact, I also noticed that when I created second node, then it gets the very same memory address as the first node and hence overwriting  the contents. Traversing the entire list after allocating the nodes on ephemeral stack allocation was anyways going to run haywire thereafter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg pointers can still continue pointing to the memory address (fairly legal in terms of current process space) they got during the call to `AddNode` function. Although they might not be valid as far as the data stored in that memory location is concerned as it might well get overwritten by further function calls as that is how stack memory is supposed to be used.

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be classes and no pointers.

Comment: @usr implementing linked lists through classes is relatively easier. I was just trying my hands to do it using structs where you land up in the world of pointers and unsafe construct as structs can't refer to themselves because of cycle issue. So this definition of `Node`  will never work `public unsafe struct Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node link;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory using native `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` (which is like malloc in C)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Linked_List
{

public unsafe class NodeList
{
    public static Node * head ;

    public void AddNode(int d)
    {

        Node* newNode = (Node*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Node)).ToPointer();
        newNode->data = d;
        newNode->link = null;

        Node* temp;
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = head;
            head = newNode;
            newNode->link = temp;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(head->data);
    }

    public void TraverseNodes()
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp->data);
            temp = temp->link;
        }
    }
}

public unsafe struct Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node* link;
}


unsafe class  Program
{
    private  static void UnsafeDSImplementation()
    {
        var myLinkedList = new NodeList();
        myLinkedList.AddNode(2);
        myLinkedList.AddNode(4);
        myLinkedList.TraverseNodes();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnsafeDSImplementation();
    }
 }
}
```

**Note**: You also need to free memory using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when head is null both head and current are pointing to same memory location. So both becomes pointers to same memory  address.
When second node is added you are changing current pointer pointed values, but since head is also pointing to same values it also changes with current.

I came at this conclusion only by reading your code, so I may not be correct. But this seems to be the reason.

Comment: The main issue was this `Node n = new Node();`. Doing this inside a function essentially does the memory allocation on stack as `Node` is a struct. The moment function ends that memory allocation is gone as your top of the stack pointers will shift back. You can not have any control on what is getting written on an unallocated orphaned memory area. I had to use Richa's `Node* newNode = (Node*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Node)).ToPointer();` code to do the allocation on `Heap` memory area of the program to persist it post the completion of `AddNode` function execution.